# writing module in python compared to R

Tags: python, r

I am new to python, so far working more on R. I am trying to learn myself - excuse me if this too basic question.

```
The following is R program / function that can output nice plot. 
     # funcomp does some calculations 
    funcomp <- function(x){
               z = x ^2 
               k= z + x 
               return(k)
               }
    #funplot apply funcomp internally and produce plot. 
    funplot <- function(x){
              y <- funcomp(x)
              plot(x,y)
              }
```

Applying the function:

```
funplot(1:10)
```

I was trying do same in python.

```
# funcomp does some calculations 
def funcomp(x):
       z = x ** 2
       k= z + x
       return k       

def funplot(x):
    y = funcomp(x)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

First I just put the above code in the python interpreter.
Applying the function, give me an error.

```
funcomp(1:10) 
funplot(1:10)
```

I saved the code in the file `trial.py` and saved to working directory. And apply the function and got same error.

```
import trial
trial.funcomp(1:10)
trial.funplot(1:10)
```

What is problem here and how can I achieve this ?

Edit: 
 I following suggestions below I tried, but does not work well:

```
trial.fumcomp(range(1,11))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fumcomp'

trial.funplot(range(1,11)) 
      2 def funcomp(x):
----> 3        z = x**2
      4        k= z + x
      5        return k

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
1:10
```

... use:

```
range(1,11)
```

Further, note that Python does not do vector calculations automatically so you have to explicitly ask Python to do that. I've used a list comprehension for that purpose in `funcomp()` (by the way, one problem is that you attempted to call `fumcomp()`, which doesn't exist in your code - hence the error message):

```
# funcomp does some calculations 
def funcomp(x):
       z = x ** 2
       k= z + x
       return k       

def funplot(x):
    y = [funcomp(xx) for xx in x]
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

Given these lines of code:

```
import trial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
trial.funplot(range(1,11))  
plt.show()
```

... the output is:

[image]

If you want Python to behave more like R, though, you would be best to use `numpy`, e.g. given the code in `trial2.py`:

```
# funcomp does some calculations 
def funcomp(x):
       z = x ** 2
       k= z + x
       return k       

def funplot(x):
    y = funcomp(x)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

The following code gives the same graph as shown above:

```
import trial2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
trial2.funplot(np.array(range(1,11)))
plt.show()
```

... because `numpy` arrays are computed as vectors, just as in R.

Comment: thanks for quick suggestion. I still getting more errors - see my edits, thanks